# Generate xcode and Android Studio project with React native

Tags: react-native

I am very new with react native. I used this command to create my first react native projects: `create-react-native-app HelloWorld`

This generates these files:

```
App.js
app.json
App.test.js
/node-modules
packages.json
README.md
yarn.lock
```

How can I generate an iOS or Android project? I tried with react-native upgrade, it generates two folders ios and android. When I open and run the ios project with xCode I get this error telling me that `index.ios.js` is missing. Shall I crated manually? I tried to put the sane content of `App.js` on it but I got an error.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html

Scroll to What about native code?